# Redirect from action in one module to action in parent project

Tags: php, yii

My main folder is `jobsite`. The `jobsite` folder is a protected folder containing `modules`,`view` and `controller` folder.

Controller folder has an `index` action and `view` has an `index` page.

My module name is `employee`, containing an action `logout`. After logout I want to redirect the `index` page in my parent project, but now it goes to the `index` page of the module `employee`.

Anybody help me?

Module `employee` controller action

```
public function actionLogout() {
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
     $this->redirect(array('site/index',));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->redirect('/site/index');
```

or

```
$this->redirect('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

right syntax is

```
 $this->redirect(array('controller/action'), 'id'=>$id);
```

So in your example, `$this->redirect(array('site/index',));` you must redirect `Site` controller's  `index` action. First check Url when redirect, check `urlManager` in config/main.php.